5.1 Surround not working correctly after Kubuntu 24.04 install
Recently I did a clean install of Kubuntu 24.04 from 22.04, and have encountered several strange issues with my sound only partially working - but what fails depends on the context.  If I am playing a mp4 from my local drive the center channel does not work at all so no dialog can be heard but all the music and sound effects are there unless I change the device from (Digital Surround HDMI) to (Digital Stereo HDMI).
Running the speaker test in System Settings/Hardware/Audio only the Left Front channel works correctly, the Right Front channel can be heard but is muffled and barely audible, and nothing from Front Center/Rear Right/Rear Left/Subwoofer
However, if I am streaming something on Hulu/Netflix the surround sound appears to be functioning perfectly.  Yet, if I'm streaming something on YouTube Front Left works, while Front Right plays through the Front Center, but none of the other speakers have sound.
Other devices connected to the Surround Sound continue working correctly through all 6 speakers, and 24 hours ago all of the above contexts worked perfectly using 22.04. I'm used to having to manually retask the jacks on the onboard sound during a clean install because it's a unique Bang&Olufsen setup with 4 internal speakers and a powered subwoofer, but those settings do not affect the audio through HDMI which uses a different sound profile.
The strangest part is a local mp4 (in VLC) plays perfect 5.1 surround only when PulseAudio is set to a 2.0 HDMI device profile, but everything else only plays the Front Left on that profile until it's changed to the 5.1 HDMI profile where everything works except the Front Right, and no matter what profile is selected only Front Left works in the Sound Test.
HP Envy m7 - Kubuntu 24.04 - 6.8.0-45-generic (64-bit)
Update: running speaker-test only finds 1 channel and tests Front Left repeatedly.  aplay -L lists the default as
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server

pacmd list-source shows the selected PulseAudio source as:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-surround.monitor> 
    state: RUNNING 
    sample spec: s16le 6ch 44100Hz 
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe 
    Surround 5.1 
    used by: 3 
    linked by: 3 

which is apparently not being used by speaker-test in spite of being  the default. Running aplay -L again to bypass the default found the correct card
    surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 HDA 
    Intel PCH, ALC3241 Analog 
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers 

to bypass the default, ran speaker-test Dsurround51:PCH -c 6 which came back
    Playback device is surround51:PCH
    Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
    Using 16 octaves of pink noise
    Channels count (6) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
    Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument

I made a little progress running
    speaker-test -c 6 -t wav /home/DTS 5.1.wav

which tested all 6 channels, but.. only Front Left and Front Center played through the correct speakers.  Front Right and Rear Right played through the subwoofer, but the subwoofer test didn't play through any speaker. Rear Left played through the Front Left speaker but at around 25% volume.
